# Why Fritzbox 7360 red LED is blinking after flashing FritzOS?

Tags: linux, router, ftp, flash, fritzbox

I bought a Fritzbox 7360 from ebay. But the whole router was configured for German ISPs and was in German, therefore I tried to flash an international version of FritzOS.

The steps I followed was the following

1. I downloaded the firmware from ftp://ftp.avm.de/fritzbox/fritzbox-7360-v1/other/fritz.os
2. I typed into a linux terminal line session:
   `ftp 192.168.178.1`
3. Then I typed the following

   ```
    bin
    passiv
    quote MEDIA FLSH
    put FRITZ.Box_Fon_WLAN_7360-06.33.image mtd1
   ```
4. Then once I flashed the  `FRITZ.Box_Fon_WLAN_7360-06.33.image` I exited the ftp session via `exit`
5. And I unplugged the router. After a while I plugged it back.

After the steps the `Info` flashes with a red color. I see it that is some sort of an indication that I have not done something appropriate. Do you have any ideas why that may happen?

I exited the ftp session once the Firmware has successfully been uploaded. Ι have no Linux Box in order to run the fritzbox recovery OS.

Comment: Can you perform a factory reset on the box?  That is what I would try next.

Comment: How I can do that? After flashing I have no Http panel at all.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know about that. Some routers have a hardware reset button. That is about the only suggestion I can make.

Comment: I do not see to have that Button

Comment: I did some looking. Everything says you need to log in. So you probably need now to call Fritzbox Support.

Comment: FritzBoxes can be reset by connecting a phone (no joke) to the router and performing the factory reset via it's keypad. Please see the [Manual](https://en.avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/EN/Manuals/FRITZ_Box/Manual_FRITZBox_7360.pdf) for further information.

EDIT: grammar

Comment: I also tried to reset via phone bt I m unable to access web ppanel as well. Also I am uunable to connect to ADAM2 via ftp. Ftp times out.

Comment: Did you try to access AVM's Support database? Despite of that the current FritzOS allows to switch the language. Did it work before flashing the firmware? I suspect you did not wait long enough for the update to finish before unplugging. Did you check via WLAN and GUI?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, you can reset your Fritz.box by accessing the recovery mode. The recovery mode can be accessed via an external phone with a working keypad (numpad). [Manual around page 129 (on phone)](https://en.avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/EN/Manuals/FRITZ_Box/Manual_FRITZBox_7360.pdf) - It is noteworthy, that not all fritzboxes are able to use the international image, especially since some of them (e.g. most German versions) are not intercompatible with international Fritz.OS versions.

Source for the last sentence: Fritz support, as i had the same question around a year ago before buying a German version FritzBox.